# Ampersand in Symfony Page Title

Tags: escaping, symfony-1.4, special-characters

On a Symfony web app I'm building, all my HTML page titles have an ampersand in them.  However, Symfony is escaping the ampersand, and my title ends up looking like this:

```
  <title>Home - Wallace &amp;amp;amp; Gromit., Inc.</title>
```

My view YAML defines the title with an unescaped ampersand:

```
default:
  ...
  metas:
    ...
    title:        Wallace & Gromit., Inc.
```

And I've tried all sorts of escaping strategies with the include_title() function in my layout.php, but nothing seems to work.

```
<head>
  <?php include_http_metas() ?>
  <?php if (has_slot('title_prefix')): ?>
    <?php $sf_context->getResponse()->setTitle(get_slot('title_prefix') . ' - ' . $sf_context->getResponse()->getTitle(ESC_SPECIALCHARS)) ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php include_metas() ?>
  <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
  <?php include_stylesheets() ?>
  <!--[if IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/screen_ie.css" /><![endif]-->
  <?php include_javascripts() ?>
  <?php include_title(ESC_SPECIALCHARS) ?>
</head>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setTitle() method has a default parameter for escaping the title.  It looks like this:

```
setTitle($title, $escape = true)
```

You shouldn't be escaping the the call to getTitle() if you are using the default parameter to setTitle().  Try using ESC_RAW instead of ESC_SPECIALCHARS.

Comment: Thanks!  This totally put me on the right track. I ended up having to pass ESC_RAW to both the include_title() function and the getTitle() function, as well as setting $escape to false.